# Two nodes MongoDB replica set without arbiter

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

Is it possible to create a MongoDB replica set consisting of only 1 primary and 1 secondary member?
I would like to have delayed replica set that will copy data from primary with delay of 24 hours. I know I can put arbiter on one of the servers (primary or secondary, I know this is not advised but my only wish is to run this configuration on two servers) and it would run fine, but I want to know if it is possible to completely kick arbiter out.
It would look like this:
[image: Two nodes replica set without arbiter]

Comment: what did u use to make the diagram tho?

Comment: I just took diagram from official mongo pages and deleted one secondary node.

Answer (score 17):

Short answer: don't.

Long answer: the way automatic failover works in MongoDB is that a replica set needs a qualified majority to successfully elect a new primary. Delayed members do have votes in elections. So if *either* of your nodes fails the replica set finds out that it doesn't have this majority and the current primary steps down even if it didn't fail. So what you essentially do is **doubling** the chances of making your replica set fail. An arbiter is a very cheap process, in term of RAM usage, CPU and even disk space when run with `--smallfiles --no-journal --noprealloc` or the equivalent options set in the config file. Note that the mentioned options are safe to use, since an arbiter essentially only checks the heartbeats of the data bearing nodes. You could put the arbiter on the application server for example.

*Disclaimer: the following procedure is strongly discouraged to use. Proceed at your own risk.*

You could set the votes of the delayed server to 0. This way the undelayed node will call for an election in case the delayed member fails, comes to the conclusion that it is the only node online of the replica set *and* that it has the majority of votes (1/1) and will continue to work as expected. This course of action needs some attention, as you will have an even number of votes again in case you add a member to the replica set later and makes it necessary to reconfigure the replica set. It also has serious implications with network fragmentation issues. Again: *Use at your own risk*

Comment: If there are only two nodes: Primary and Secondary and Secondary fails, the whole system becomes unavailable for writes as I understand it. Can you point me to a motivation why MongoDB developers chose to implement failover this way, seems high availability was not their prime concern or am I missing something?

Comment: @racic: Because you are not supposed to have only two nodes. The smallest number in a replica set is 3.

Comment: @racic It was implemented that way to avoid the [split-brain problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing)) where _both_ isolated nodes think they're the primary.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can and all you really need to do is set the member to not be eligible for primary.

There is documentation on how to make sure a member cannot be elected as primary here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-secondary-only-replica-set-member/

Comment: As Markus mentioned "votes" should be set to 0 on Standby node. Otherwise if you have just 2 nodes and second (Standby) goes down, PRIMARY immediately changes to be a "SECONDARY" so at it thinks its single vote is not democratic to keep itself as PRIMARY. (tested on version: 2.6.12)

Comment: @Zaur a single vote won't satisfy the quorum, but if I remember right that method has been called into question a few times but TBH it has been a while since I have looked at this topic since doing this in any form is considered as breaking MongoDB

Comment: @Zaur I wrote "could" and I highly discourage fiddling with votes. Sammaye is right that fiddling with votes might well break failover capabilities in rather unexpected ways, as written. For me, the additional price of a cheapo VM for the arbiter is a no-brainer when comparing it to the risk of basically making the whole setup useless and the certainty that it is more fragile than it needs to be.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg MongoDb will see the other nodes even if they don't have a vote

Comment: @Sammaye Correct. But actually, isn't it the number of votes that count? If I am not mistaken, it is.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible but not recommended. The caveat of this approach is no automatic failovers.

If you primary goes down then you will have to manually make the other server as primary.

If you are keeping you secondary only as a mirror of your primary and you are fine with manual failover then it should work for you.

More info here:

http://openmymind.net/Does-My-Replica-Set-Need-An-Arbiter/

Comment: That is not quite correct and in parts even dangerously wrong. Your replica set will revert to secondary if _either_ of your nodes fails. In this situation, you would have to reconfigure your replica set in order to force a node to become primary. Depending on how you do it, this might cause data loss in case the node which just went down holds data which had not made it to the other node yet. With the node being removed from the replica set for example, a necessary rollback might not be detected and the data diffs to be manually identified.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the best option is add an arbiter. I tried before with votes, but on 2 nodes replicaset you can have some issues with sync.