# MongoDb preparing for Sharded Clusters

Tags: mongodb, configuration, cluster-computing, replication, sharding

We are currently setting up our mongodb environment for production. At the moment we only have one dedicated mongodb database server. We will expand this in the near future with a 2nd server and I already indicated to the management that for the ideal situation we should get a 3rd server as well.

Since I already know we're going to use sharding and replication in the near future I want to be prepared for it.

The idea I have now is to start now with the Development Configuration (as mongo's documentation names it).

[image: Mongodb Development setup]

Whenever our second server comes available I would like to expand this setup to a configuration with 2 configuration servers en 2 shards (replica sets). 
[image: MongoDb Shared cluster]

And of course when our third server comes available have the fully functional sharded cluster configuration.

While reading mongo's documentation I was getting triggered by the note that de Development setup should not be used in production.

[MongoDb Development Configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharded-cluster-components/#development-configuration)

Keeping in mind that we will add more servers soon, would it be a bad idea to already configure the Development Configuration already so we can easily add the 2nd server to the cluster when it comes available?

Comment: Good question, but I think it is outside the scope of programming; so it belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com really.

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the 'development sharded setup' I've found my anwser. Of course i'm happy to share in case anybody runs into the same questions as I do when starting with this.

In my case, it was ok to start with the development setup untill my new servers arrived. It was a temporary situation and when my new servers arived I was able to easily expand my replicasets. There are a number of reasons why this isn't adviced for production:

To state the obvious, there is no replication yet. Since I was running shards on one machine there is a single point of failure. If the machine, or one node goes down, the cluster won't work anymore.

Now this part is interesting. After I added a second server, I did have primary and secondary nodes. Primary nodes were used for writing and secondary for reading. I've eliminated the issue that there was no replication AND my data had a higher availability. However, **I noticed with the 2-member replica sets, if one member of the replicaset went down (even is this was a secondary), the primary stepped down to a secondary node as well**. This had to do with the voting mechanism that MongoDb uses. [See Markus' more detailed answer on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515526/758993). Since there are no more primaries in the replicaset, my cluster won't function anymore. Now, if i were to use an arbiter I could eliminate this problem as well.

When you have a 3-member replicataset, automatic failover kicks in. Whenever a node goes down, another primary is assigned automatically and the cluster will continue performing as before.

During my tests I also got to a point where one of my MongoD.exe instances stopped working due to a "Out of memory exception". I was running a cluster with 3 replicasets, meaning every machine had at least 4 mongod.exe processes running (3 for the replicaset shards and one for the configuration server replicaset). Besides having a query which wasn't optimized yet I also noticed that the [WiredTiger storage engine by default can use up to 50% of ram minus one gigabyte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use). Perhaps it wasn't the best choise to have multiple replicaset-shards on one machine but I was able to eliminate the problem by capping the wiredtiger memory usage.

I hope this answer helps anybody who's starting to set up replication and sharding for MongoDb.