# Connection to mongodb replicaset fails when one of the members is unavailable

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have a mongodb replicaset with the following configuration

```
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 2,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-0.mongodb-mongodb-replicaset.default.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-1.mongodb-mongodb-replicaset.default.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            }
    ],
    "settings" : {
            "chainingAllowed" : true,
            "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
            "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
            "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
            "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
            "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
            "getLastErrorModes" : {

            },
            "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                    "w" : 1,
                    "wtimeout" : 0
            },
            "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5c65617521068bf38fd3634a")
    }
```

}
To test failover scenarios, I killed one of the members and tried to connect to the replicaset using mongodb node js driver. 
The connection string is as follows:

```
const url = mongodb+srv://mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-client.default.svc.cluster.local/users?replicaSet=rs0
```

The connection fails with the following error:

```
{ Error: failed to connect to server [mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-1.mongodb-mongodb-replicaset.default.svc.cluster.local:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.8.2.12:27017]
at Pool.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Connection.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
at Socket.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I have tried connecting with `connectWithNoPrimary:true` as well but the same error occurs. Is this expected behaviour ? or there is something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a replica set with only two members & no arbiter -- this means that it's not able to elect a new leader which means there's nothing to connect to after you failover. Take a look at [Two nodes MongoDB replica set without arbiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502410/two-nodes-mongodb-replica-set-without-arbiter) for a much better description of what's going on.

Comment: I have tested the same process with a three node replica set as well. The error occurs.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd take a look at the connection string then -- "The mongodb+srv option will fail if there is no available DNS with records that correspond to the hostname identified in the connection string." It sounds like that `default` in the connection string might not be getting updated appropriately.  Connection strings for replica sets often look like `mongodb://db0.example.com:27017,db1.example.com:27017,db2.example.com:27017/admin` where each member is specified in the url

Comment: Right. My first try was with a connection string like that. But that threw the error `db-1` failed to connect when db1 was down. So I thought maybe using a headless service might be the way to go. So that the client will just connect to whatever mongos are available. But I guess thats not possible. All the replica set members have to reachable for the connection to be successful.